# What prop type should I check for requiring the source?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-proptypes

I'm writing a project based on `react native`. I'm using `prop-types` for type checking of components. now I wanna wrap `Image` component of `react-native` in my own `Image` component. In the following code see my own `Image` component:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Image as ImageNative } from 'react-native';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

const Image = ({ style, source }) => (
  <ImageNative source={source} style={style} />
);

Image.defaultProps = {
  style: {}
};

Image.propTypes = {
  style: PropTypes.oneOfType([PropTypes.object, PropTypes.array]),
  source: PropTypes.any.isRequired
};

export default Image;
```

Each place I decide to use my own `Image` component, I will import it and use it like below:

```
<Image source={require('assets/images/splashSignInAsset.png')} />
```

Actually, I checked `source` prop inside my own `Image` component as *any*.

```
source: PropTypes.any.isRequired
```

But it's not true. I know it. I don't know what should I write there. What is the type of `require` function return value which I checked it here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Currently is possible this statement as a type:

```js
import { ImageProps } from 'react-native';

interface Props {
  imageSource: ImageProps['source'];
}
```

Where `ImageProps['source']` will return the correct type from the package and also receive further updates.

Comment: Glad to help @AmerllicA :)

Comment: `_reactNative.ImageProps` is undefined? v0.61.5

Answer (score 20):

Actually, I refuse to use `any`. the good answer is `node`.

When I insert `require('assets/images/splashSignInAsset.png')` function inside my `Image` component, I must check the `node` prop type, like the following:

```
Image.propTypes = {
  style: PropTypes.oneOfType([PropTypes.object, PropTypes.array]),
  source: PropTypes.node.isRequired
};
```

But I think the right answer is using `React Native` component prop type for the `source`:

```
import { Image as ImageNative } from 'react-native';
...
Image.propTypes = {
  style: PropTypes.oneOfType([PropTypes.object, PropTypes.array]),
  source: ImageNative.propTypes.source.isRequired
};
```

### Update:

Also, the exact answer is using `source` prop type in the `react-native` source code, so the best answer is like following code:

```
source: PropTypes.oneOfType([
  PropTypes.shape({
    uri: PropTypes.string,
    headers: PropTypes.objectOf(PropTypes.string)
  }),
  PropTypes.number,
  PropTypes.arrayOf(
    PropTypes.shape({
      uri: PropTypes.string,
      width: PropTypes.number,
      height: PropTypes.number,
      headers: PropTypes.objectOf(PropTypes.string)
    })
  )
])
```